# how do I parametrise a stochastic matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I have a matrix $\mathbf{t}$ that maps one $d$ dimensional probability distribution to another $\mathbf{t}^T x = q$, i.e. with $\sum\limits_i t_{ij} x_i = q_j$ and $\sum\limits_j t_{ij} = 1$ $\forall$ $i$. Given that I know $x$ and $q$, how manay parameters do I need to specify $\mathbf{t}$? For example, take the case where $d=2$, using $\sum\limits_i t_{ij} x_i = q_j$ and $\sum\limits_j t_{ij} = 1$ $\forall$ $i$ I can parametrise $\mathbf{t}$ in terms of any one of its elements. $x=(x_1,x_2)$ and $q=(q_1,q_2)$, choosing the element $t_{22}$ I get

\begin{align}
t_{11} &= \frac{q_1 - (t_{21} x_2)}{x_1}=\frac{q_1 - x_2 (1-t_{22})}{x_1} \\
t_{12} &= 1-t_{11} = 1-\frac{q_1 - x_2 (1-t_{22})}{x_1} \\
t_{21} &= 1-t_{22} \\
t_{22} &= t_{22}
\end{align}

so I only need to specify a single element in the $d=2$ case to parametrise the matrix $\mathbf{t}$. How do I extend this to the case $d=3$? and higher dimensions? And what is the specific parametrisation in terms of the remaining degrees of freedom, as in the above case but for $d=3,4,\cdot\cdot\cdot$

Answer (score 1):

Beware! In your explanation of why your $2 \times 2$ matrix can be parameterized by $t_{22}$, you divide through by $x_1$, which is to say that you assume that $x_1 \neq 0$.

Instead, you can explicitly write out your conditions on the elements of $\mathbf{t}$ in a matrix equation:

$$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
x_1 & x_2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & x_1 & x_2 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right]
\left[
\begin{matrix}
t_{11} \\ t_{21} \\ t_{12} \\ t_{22}
\end{matrix}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{matrix}
q_1 \\ q_2 \\ 1 \\ 1
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

Generally, we can write

$$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
x^T & & 0 \\
& \ddots &  \\
0 & & x^T \\
I & \cdots & I
\end{matrix}
\right]
\left[
\begin{matrix}
\mathbf{t}_1 \\
\vdots \\
\mathbf{t}_n
\end{matrix}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{matrix}
q_1 \\ \vdots \\ q_n \\
1 \\ \vdots \\ 1
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

More compactly, we can write

$$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
I \otimes x^T \\ 1^T \otimes I
\end{matrix}
\right]
\text{vec}(\mathbf{t})
=
\left[
\begin{matrix}
q \\ 1
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

Where $I \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ is the identity, $1 \in \mathbb{R}^d$ is a vector of all $1$s, and $\otimes$ is the Kronecker product. We're essentially asking for the rank of

$$
A:=
\left[
\begin{matrix}
I \otimes x^T \\ 1^T \otimes I
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

Then the number of free parameters necessary for specifying $\mathbf{t}$ is $d^2 - \text{rank}(A)$.

It's easier to compute $\text{rank}(A)$ by looking at $A^T$, i.e., looking at $A$'s row rank. $A^T$ looks like

$$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
x & & 0 & I \\
& \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & & x & I
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

$A^T$ is not full column rank: $A^T [\begin{matrix} 1 & -x \end{matrix}]^T = 0$. You can prove $\text{rank}(A) \geq 2d -1$ by moving the stack of identities to just after the first column:

$$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
x_1 & I & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & I & x_2 & & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & & \ddots & \\
0 & I & 0 & & x_n 
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

Now the last $2d - 1$ columns form a lower triangular matrix and so are linearly independent (more rigorously, they form a matrix whose rows can be permuted such that the matrix is lower triangular and with all non-zeros on the diagonal).

So $\text{rank}(A^T) = \text{rank}(A) = 2d-1$ and $\mathbf{t}$ is specified by $d^2 - 2d + 1 = (d-1)^2$ free parameters.

I wonder if there's a simpler way to prove this? The $(d-1)^2$ free parameters suggests that $\mathbf{t}$ can be defined by its top $d-1 \times d-1$ minor? I wonder if there's any relation to affine algebra, where matrices are usually constrained in that way...

Comment: thanks very much for this answer, lots of effort gone in and very useful so thank you! If you also happen to know how to do the parametrisation as above in my question but for a trit instead of a bit I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 0):

In general, if $T$ is a $n\times n$ stochastic matrix we can parametrize each row with $n-1$  elements and hence $T$ has $n(n-1)$ parameters.

Comment: Thanks - in the case above $n=2$ and I can parametrise it with a single parameter, because I know the initial and final probability distributions, so this does better than $n(n-1)$.